# How and can I dynamically create a subclass of an unknown class?

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic-programming

Here is my scenario. I have a plugin system. The plugins can detect and lookup each other at run time via a master list of plugins.
The hierarchy is such

```
Base Class A
----Unknown Class B extends A
--------Known method from Class A, we'll call it E
--------Dynamically generated Class F extends B
------------Overridden Method E
------------Other methods inherited from A and B
```

F should inherit behavior from B, with the exception that E is overridden. F is then instantiated separately from B as a different object with similar but not identical behavior. The class B is not known at compile time, but it can be identified with an iteration and check for instance of A in the master list of plugins.

My specific case involves a game. Not necessarily what I'm doing, but a good example would be finding every sword added by other plugins, and then making a new copy of the sword, with all the same abilities, except it shoots fire instead of whatever fancy swing effect it may have had originally, and method E determines what happens when the sword is swung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bytecode engineering toolkit like [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/). It allows you to
[create new classes based on your existing class](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html#pool) and lets you [change the method body](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#intro).

Comment: Thanks for the links. My issue is not knowing enough about the solution to accurately search for it. I'll take a look, but at first glance, it looks like what I want.